# How to load a video into a separate div when click on a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, video-streaming

I have these 2 divs - one contains the menu, where each element of the list will be a link to a video, and I want the corresponding video to be loaded into the div, which is right next to the first one.

I was thinking about forms, but this is not quite a good idea. And I have no knowledge in JavaScript or JQuery, so some solutions, provided with explanation how to use, will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

On click of the Video URL, first if its an anchor, use preventDefault and block the click behavior, next bind your own onclick event on that element.

On-click of that element should actually use the next div's id and be able to play ur video in that div in whatever manner you want.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="link">http://youtu.be/Etst4t3ES8Y</a><br/>
<a href="javascript:;" class="link">http://youtu.be/Etst4t3ES8Y</a><br/>
<a href="javascript:;" class="link">http://youtu.be/Etst4t3ES8Y</a><br/>
<br/>
<div id="videoDiv"></div>
```

jQuery :

```
$('.link').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var url =$(this).html();
    $("#videoDiv").html('<iframe width="400" height="400" src="'+url+'?wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');

})
```